# Go AOP is not catching my aspects

Tags: php, windows, iis, aop, goaop

I am trying to use GO AOP to allow me to use aspects with a PHP project that I am working on. I used composer to install the goaop/framework. I have written the files for my aspect as follows. I know CalendarController runs because in one of the functions has an echo I can see. Do you know why this isn't working?

index.php

```
// Initialize an application aspect container
$applicationAspectKernel = App\Http\applicationAspectKernel::getInstance();
$applicationAspectKernel->init(array(
    'debug' => true, // use 'false' for production mode
    // Cache directory
    'cacheDir'  => __DIR__ . '/path/to/cache/for/aop',
    // Include paths restricts the directories where aspects should be applied, or empty for all source files
    'includePaths' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../app'
    )
));
```

MonitorAspect.php

```
namespace Aspects;

use Go\Aop\Aspect;
use Go\Aop\Intercept\FieldAccess;
use Go\Aop\Intercept\MethodInvocation;
use Go\Lang\Annotation\After;
use Go\Lang\Annotation\Before;
use Go\Lang\Annotation\Around;
use Go\Lang\Annotation\Pointcut;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class MonitorAspect implements Aspect
{



    /**
     * Method that will be called before real method
     *
     * @param MethodInvocation $invocation Invocation
     * @Before("execution(public App\Http\Controllers\CalendarController->*(*))")
     */
    public function beforeMethodExecution(MethodInvocation $invocation)
    {
        \Monolog\Handler\error_log("Is this being called at all? Yes");
        $obj = $invocation->getThis();
        echo 'Calling Before Interceptor for method: ',
             is_object($obj) ? get_class($obj) : $obj,
             $invocation->getMethod()->isStatic() ? '::' : '->',
             $invocation->getMethod()->getName(),
             '()',
             ' with arguments: ',
             json_encode($invocation->getArguments()),
             "<br>\n";
    }
}
```

applicationAspectKernel.php
    namespace App\Http;

```
use Go\Core\AspectKernel;
use Go\Core\AspectContainer;
use Aspects\MonitorAspect;

/**
 * Description of aspectKernel
 *
 * 
 */
class applicationAspectKernel extends AspectKernel{

        /**
     * Configure an AspectContainer with advisors, aspects and pointcuts
     *
     * @param AspectContainer $container
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureAop(AspectContainer $container)
    {
        $container->registerAspect(new MonitorAspect());
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Fixed the @Before statement.

Comment: I've trying for 2 days, and getting this stuck too :(. Have you resolved this problem?

Comment: Are you using a windows os by any chance. Also please note the edit I just made.

Comment: I did fix it sort of. For some reason, Windows IIS doesn't work with aspects, no idea why.  Others claimed they got it working with WAMP or MAMP (not sure which), this didn't work for me, but a friend ported my code to his Mac and it worked with the edit I posted (he made the original correction). So I kind of rage quit windows and put the whole thing on a ubuntu server VM.  Not sure if that was the best method but it worked.

Comment: Can you confirm that your web server can write into the `cacheDir` path?

Comment: My project still did not work, @wolfcall could you show me the your full example project?

Comment: Honestly lethanh that is almost the whole project. The only thing missing is the calendar class. I didn't use any other files except an empty test class which was replaced later by other team members. I didn't do anything else on this project. Sorry dude. What are you using to host your project (windows, linux, mac?)